# wrapping div around string using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do i wrap a div class `div class="includingVAT"></div>` around the string text :`incl. MwSt`

```
<span id="VariantPrice_3181">
<span class="variantprice">
<span class="pricelabel">Preis&nbsp;</span>
240,00 (CHF)
</span>
&nbsp;incl. MwSt
<span id="plus-shipping">plus-shipping</span>
</span>
```

using jquery?

it needs to look like this:

```
<span id="VariantPrice_3181">
<span class="variantprice">
<span class="pricelabel">Preis&nbsp;</span>
240,00 (CHF)
</span>
<div class="includingVAT">&nbsp;incl. MwSt</div>
<span id="plus-shipping">plus-shipping</span>
</span>
```

the string without span or div needs the div class includingVAT as there could be different language translations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this example here: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Jz9fr/9/)

```
var text = $('#plus-shipping').map(function(){
    return this.previousSibling.nodeValue
});
$('#plus-shipping').prepend('<div class="includingVAT">' + text[0] + '</div>');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".pricelabel").after('<div class="includingVAT">');
$(".plus-shipping").before('</div>');
```

This is awkward and error-prone. Is there any-way you can insert the *whole* `div`? Why does **incl. MwSt** exist only in the HTML?

Comment: i managed to create a div in the string resources section of the cart. Its not ideal but it works. thanks anyway for this.

Comment: No problem. Glad you found a solution.

Comment: Haven't gotten round to finishing that yet :D